GA4 Event conversion rates in looker studio
I am looking to create a calculation between two events in looker studio with GA4 Data.
the data is from the same source and i have tried all the varients of when / if and case . In theory this should be pretty simple and feel like i am missing something here.
sum ( event name = "XXXX"/ event name = "XXXX") but what i see if that the event name is not the event count which is why it is erroring.
the data is currently in a pivot table format and i was looking to add new metrics to show the % variation in the stages of the funnel.
